# WPF datagrid. Cannot highlight custom styled cell

Tags: wpf, datagrid, styles, cell, highlight

I have a datagrid which is a financial calculator with some cells that turn red on negative values. This is done via DataTrigger with converter. I also have overridden system highlight selection color. My problem now is that when I select a row the red cells don't get highlighted.

[Here's the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F6hx9.png)

As far as I understand the custom cell style overrides selection. I want that my custom red cell be highlighted with 0.5 opacity blue bar just as well. How can I fix this?

Well, I can add an extra trigger to the cell style that changes BG color upon selection and tweak the color to fit, but that's rather a kludge. Or maybe I can implement an overlay color with opacity here somehow?

```
<Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightBlue" />
</Trigger>
```

Below is the full code. This is a stripped down, light weight but fully working example.

XAML

```
 <Window.Resources>
        <local:ValueToBoolConverter x:Key="ValueToBoolConverter"/>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding MainTable}"
                  AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                  CanUserAddRows="False">
            <DataGrid.RowStyle>
                <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Azure"/>
                    <Style.Resources>
                        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="Blue" Opacity="0.5" />
                        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightTextBrushKey}" Color="Black" />
                        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.InactiveSelectionHighlightBrushKey}" Color="Transparent" />
                    </Style.Resources>
                </Style>
            </DataGrid.RowStyle>
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Income Day" Binding="{Binding IncomeDay}" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Income Week" Binding="{Binding IncomeWeek}">
                    <DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
                            <Style.Triggers>
                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IncomeWeek, Converter={StaticResource ValueToBoolConverter}}" Value="true">
                                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Salmon"/>
                                </DataTrigger>
                            </Style.Triggers>
                        </Style>
                    </DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
                </DataGridTextColumn>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Income Month" Binding="{Binding IncomeMonth}" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Income Year" Binding="{Binding IncomeYear}" Width="*" />
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
```

C#

```
using System;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Data;

namespace Datagrid_Cell_Highlight
{
    public class TableData
    {
        public decimal IncomeDay { get; set; }
        public decimal IncomeWeek { get; set; }
        public decimal IncomeMonth { get; set; }
        public decimal IncomeYear { get; set; }
    }

    public class ViewModel
    {
        public ObservableCollection<TableData> MainTable { get; set; }
        public ViewModel()
        {
            MainTable = new ObservableCollection<TableData>
            {
                new TableData { IncomeDay = (decimal)1.11 },
                new TableData { IncomeDay = (decimal)2.22 },
                new TableData { IncomeDay = (decimal)-1.23 },
                new TableData { IncomeDay = (decimal)-2.34 }
            };
            foreach (var table in MainTable)
            {
                table.IncomeWeek = table.IncomeDay * 7;
                table.IncomeMonth = table.IncomeDay * 30;
                table.IncomeYear = table.IncomeDay * 365;
            }
        }
    }

    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = new ViewModel();
        }
    }

    public class ValueToBoolConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if ((value is decimal) && ((decimal)value < 0))
                return true;
            else return false;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Kludge" or not, the `Background` of the cell will indeed "override" the background of the row so you should add another trigger to the cell style that takes this into consideration. You could for example use a `MultiDataTrigger` and a `DrawingBrush` that contains both a red and a blue brush:

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="Income Week" Binding="{Binding IncomeWeek}">
    <DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IncomeWeek, Converter={StaticResource ValueToBoolConverter}}" Value="true">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Salmon"/>
                </DataTrigger>
                <MultiDataTrigger>
                    <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Condition Binding="{Binding IncomeWeek, Converter={StaticResource ValueToBoolConverter}}" Value="true" />
                        <Condition Binding="{Binding IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="True" />
                    </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Setter Property="Background">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <DrawingBrush Viewport="0,0,1,1" TileMode="Tile">
                                <DrawingBrush.Drawing>
                                    <DrawingGroup>
                                        <GeometryDrawing>
                                            <GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
                                                <RectangleGeometry Rect="0,0,1,1" />
                                            </GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
                                            <GeometryDrawing.Brush>
                                                <SolidColorBrush Color="Salmon"/>
                                            </GeometryDrawing.Brush>
                                        </GeometryDrawing>
                                        <GeometryDrawing>
                                            <GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
                                                <RectangleGeometry Rect="0,0,1,1" />
                                            </GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
                                            <GeometryDrawing.Brush>
                                                <SolidColorBrush Color="Blue" Opacity="0.2"/>
                                            </GeometryDrawing.Brush>
                                        </GeometryDrawing>
                                    </DrawingGroup>
                                </DrawingBrush.Drawing>
                            </DrawingBrush>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </MultiDataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
</DataGridTextColumn>
```

Comment: Does exactly what I need. Accepted.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using MultiDataTrigger. But why do you think this is a "kludge"? I think it is rather elegant.

An alternate to mm8's code is to simply set two MultiDataTriggers. The first one to trigger when IsSelected is false and the second way when IsSelected is true.

```
<DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
    <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">            
        <Style.Triggers>
            <MultiDataTrigger>
                <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Condition Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=IsSelected}" Value="False"/>
                    <Condition Binding="{Binding IncomeWeek, Converter={StaticResource ValueToBoolConverter}}" Value="True"/>
                </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                <MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Salmon"/>
                </MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
            </MultiDataTrigger>
            <MultiDataTrigger>
                <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Condition Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=IsSelected}" Value="True"/>
                    <Condition Binding="{Binding IncomeWeek, Converter={StaticResource ValueToBoolConverter}}" Value="True"/>
                </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                <MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}}"/>
                    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
                </MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
            </MultiDataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
```

Comment: This works, upvoted, but I accepted mm8's answer because his implements opacity. As for "kludge", I can't see a simple way to reuse this approach for multiple columns. But that's maybe another question.